# Keras for multiple digit recognition

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am trying to understand CNNs through some exercises in Keras (theano backend). I am unable to fit the model below (Error: AttributeError: 'Convolution2D' object has no attribute 'get_shape').  This dataset is images (28*28) from the MNIST data concatenated together for a maximum of five images.  So the input shape should be 1, 28, 140 (grayscale = 1, height =28, width = 28*5)

The goal is to predict the sequence of numbers. Thank you!!

```
batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 2

img_rows =28
img_cols=140
img_channels = 1

model_input=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)

x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same')(model_input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
conv_out = Flatten()(x)

x1 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)
x2 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)
x3 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)
x4 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)
x5 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)

lst = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

model = Sequential(input=model_input, output=lst)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, data_labels, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the input layer. Do the following change:

```
model_input=Input(shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols))
```

provided your `image_dim_ordering` is `th`. Import the `Input` layer from `keras.layers`.

I also notice that there are multiple outputs. So you need to use Function model instead of Sequential. Just change it to:

```
model = Model(input=model_input, output=lst)
```

Import `Model` from `keras.models`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am still getting that the tensor object is not iterable.

Comment: Is the error at `model.fit()`. If so my guess will be that `data_labels` should be a list of numpy arrays of length 5. Each of the numpy arrays should of dimension `dataset.shape[0] x nb_classes`

Comment: Hi the error is in the activation layer. Here is a link to the full code: https://gist.github.com/jdills26/ca69e59ef19d4993636f6b50a7cbe514  Thank you for any help!  Here is the data source: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html

Comment: Ok I notice some problems. 1. `dataset=dataset[:,np.newaxis,:,:]` This will fix the input shape to take in the channels. 2. The output is not proper according to the tensor graph created. The format should be as mentioned in the earlier comment. I have commented on the gist for a rough fix(may have some error but it will give you the idea).